# Excel: How to create custom age-range groups in a Pivot Table?

Tags: excel, range, customization, grouping, pivot-table

I have the following data list with two columns: 'Division' and 'Age.'

[image: Data Set]

I want to put this data into a Pivot Table and group the ages into specified ranges; however, I'm having issues figuring out how to get around grouping them into set increments that don't vary.  My first range would need to be 18-24, my next would be 25-29, then 30-34, 35-39, and so on until I hit 64. Then, I would have 65+ all grouped into one, like so:

[image: Custom Age Ranges]

The "Group" option provided in the Pivot Table selection doesn't let me customize my ranges so that my first range can include 6 values while my second only includes 5 values.

Is there a formula that could accomplish this task?

Any help you can provide would be much appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: I know new users aren't able to embed pictures, but writing the tables out would help others and increase your chance of getting an answer.

Comment: Which version of Excel are you using?  Are you using the classic pivot table layout?

Comment: @B540Glenn I was using Excel 2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start your groups at 25, Excel will automatically group anything below 25 into its own <25  bucket. Then add a filter to the Labels to only include those that are greater than or equal to 18. Now your <25 bucket really represents 18-25. If you want to, you can click on that cell and rename the group "18-25", it will still count the same records.

This:
[image: Groupings]

Then this:
[image: Label Filters]

Comment: Ah, perfect! A solution so simple, yet it passed me by.  Thank you for your help!